# proxy in package.json does not resolve CORS error

Tags: reactjs, flask, axios, proxy, cors

I don't understand why I'm getting a CORS issue:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I put a proxy to port 5000 in my `package.json`, since my React server is running on port 3000 and my Flask server is running on port 5000. I am trying to avoid using CORS by simply using a proxy server, but it doesn't seem to be working.

*I thought the proxy would redirect requests from React on port 3000 to itself on port 5000 and then send those requests to the Flask server also on port 5000. In that way it should address the CORS issue since the proxy and the Flask server come from the same origin.*

Please correct me if I am wrong and tell me what I should do to resolve this problem - I'm a newbie to proxies and Flask.

error

[image]

terminal output at time of error

[image]

RELEVANT CODE

`package.json`

```
{...
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
...}
```

`api.py`

```
from flask import Flask, session, request, redirect, jsonify
import pyrebase

app = Flask(__name__)

firebaseConfig = {...}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)
auth = firebase.auth()

app.secret_key = "secret"

@app.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
    """
    Signin user. Return a redirect response with profile url
    """
    print("----------------LOGIN----------------")
    email = request.form["email"]
    password = request.form["password"]

    try:
        user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
        session["user_id"] = user["idToken"]
        print("Current User:\n", user['email'])
        print("Redirecting to profile page...")
        return redirect('http://localhost:5000/profile')
    except Exception as e:
        print("----------------LOGIN ERROR----------------")
        print("Invalid email or password. Try again!", e)
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 400

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Login.tsx**

```
import Title from "../components/Title";
import InputUserPass from "../components/InputUserPass";

export default function Login() {
  return (
    <div className="login">
      <div className="app_title">
        <Title />
      </div>
      <InputUserPass authentication={"login"} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**InputUserPass.tsx**

```
import useUserStore from "../useUserStore";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/esm/Button";
import axios from "axios";

interface InputUserPassProps {
  authentication: "signup" | "login";
}

export default function InputUserPass({ authentication }: InputUserPassProps) {
  const { email, password, setEmail, setPassword } = useUserStore();
  const url = "http://localhost:5000/" + authentication;

  const handleButtonClick = async () => {
    axios
      .post(url, new URLSearchParams({ email: email, password: password }), {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.redirected) window.location.href = response.data.url;
        else console.log(response.data);
      });
  };

  return (
    // added onSubmit to prevent posting twice to server
    <div className="input_user_pass">
      <form action={url} method="POST" onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email: </label>
          <input
            className="field"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            type="text"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          ></input>
        </div>

        <div>
          <label htmlFor="password">Password: </label>
          <input
            className="field"
            id="password"
            name="password"
            type="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          ></input>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Button
            variant="outline-light"
            as="input"
            type="submit"
            value="Submit"
            onClick={handleButtonClick}
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## PREVIOUS ATTEMPTS:

So far I tried the following which all failed, hence my post:

1. Deleting package-lock.json and re-installing it.
2. tried using a proxy in axios, which I since removed in `InputUserPass.tsx`:

```
  const handleButtonClick = async () => {
    axios
      .post(url, new URLSearchParams({ email: email, password: password }), {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        proxy: {
          protocol: "http",
          host: "127.0.0.1",
          port: 5000,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.redirected) window.location.href = response.data.url;
        else console.log(response.data);
      });
  };
```

3. I've also tried CORS extensively and to no avail, so I'd like to explore a proxy solution.